# Why is it necessary for me to write 6 character if just one is missing and what can I do if I don't have enough reputation for write a comment?

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits

I found a intrested question in here:
[How can I loop an animation continuously in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767286/jquery-continuously-loop-animation)
One response to this was:

```
script type="text/javascript"    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 

$(function () {    
        move();
        });
function move(){
     $(".boxtext").ready(function(){
     $(".boxtext").animate({bottom:"600px"},50000,function(){
         $(".boxtext").css({"bottom":0}, move););

 });move();
 });
 </script>
```

And I would liked to add the missed opening tag for:

`script type="text/javascript"    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js">`.

In order to look like:
`<script type="text/javascript"    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js">`

But I get a red error messange for:

"Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?"
Well, I tryed write a comment, but I no have enough reputation.
How can I say that this character is missing?

Comment: Fixed it for you. The answer to your question is: You can't, until you've earned sufficient reputation to either post comments or edit without approval.

Comment: I think this isent good, and this situation is a good example why.
If a beginer search for a correct answer, he/she dosen't whant any inchorect code in the answer.
And If the anwer cannot be fix it, how can be good?

Comment: No, it's perfectly fine as it is. Usually there is much more that needs to be fixed, and new users need to be monitored before they're able to do unsupervised edits to make sure they're familiar with how things work here (and to make sure they're not just making meaningless edits in order to earn rep). There are many other questions that have been asked (and answered) here about why the reputation and minimum edit requirements exist. Search for them. If you want the ability to post comments or edit without review, earn the privileges to do so like we all do. :-)

Comment: This support/discussion/feature-request is far too broad. And all the constituent parts are duplicates.

Comment: I have a serious philosophical objection to the 6 character rule for quoted code. In programming, a single character can be a very significant change, well worth fixing if it is wrong even if the rest of the post is absolutely perfect.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan If it is an error worth fixing, somebody with sufficient rep will eventually see it and fix it. Your observation about the significance of a single character in programming is true but is not logically connected to the necessity of allowing low-rep users to make the change.

Comment: But the most user not have enough reputation fix the answer, then how can be fix it?
And I mention in the answer:
What about a jquery script?
What if just one comma missing in the line end?
 Somehow it should be given the opportunity to indicate a lack of one or two characters in the text.

Answer (score 6):

**Focus on what you can do, not on what you can't do.**

You must at least edit 6 characters to increase the chance that your edit is substantial. When you make an edit at your reputation level, your edit must be reviewed and approved by other people. Editing one character might improve the post, but not substantially, and it's not worth it to let people review such edits. If you really can't find anything else to fix or improve leaving a comment is indeed the right way to go.

Comments seem to be mostly restricted to reduce the usage of comments for things they aren't meant for. Since you can't post comments, you are more or less forced to watch how other people comment. Fairly often you will see that someone else will notice the error too and will either correct it or post a comment.

Most basic functionality unlocks fairly soon if you contribute positively to the site. You can increase your reputation by making high-quality edits to posts and posting a high-quality question or answer. You can [read the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for basic guidance and look at positive contributions of other people.

Comment: Okey but if I 'am a very new user in the javascript-html word and I just looking for a solution for a simple problem, and I found this answer,copy to my website and then I see this dosen't work, becouse the page write as text this code to the webpage, easily led to believe that this is the wrong solution.
And so, of course, is also a funicular very easily over a considerably good solution, because the whole answer or even a single or two character missing.

Comment: But I go further, what if a jquery script lacks the trailing comma, so it is not even easy to spot a user not familiar with javascript.
Somehow it should be given the opportunity to indicate a lack of one or two characters in the text.

Comment: As I said: Focus on what you can do, not what you can't do. If everyone could do everything with 1 reputation, the amount of crap that comes through would be unmanageable. Focus on what you can do: Write good questions and/or write good answers. If you do that, the ability to write comments will unlock very soon.

Comment: I don't say that this change must be happend immediately.
Make a differend option forexample "little change" and this suggest must be also aporved by community. 
And what will I do?
Just leave the anwer in incorrect?
How many people try use until this "wrong" answer?
I just would like to help fix this answer, even I not have correct questions yet.
Forexample I not have correct english skills, and that's becouse I ask and I answer in rarely.
But if I can find the answer somewhere a syntax error, eager to fix it, if this is possible.